# How do I setup a subdomain in Azure to access a folder?

Tags: c#, azure, dns, subdomain

I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzjMi3DO2xU) and successfully configured some domains.

- domain.com
- www.domain.com
- static.domain.com

`domain.com` and `www.domain.com` are working exactly as it should. But for `static.domain.com` I want to do something different. I want to access the `Static` folder on my application when I go to this domain.

How can I configure it so when I try to access `static.domain.com/all.js` it will access the contents of the `Static` folder of my application?

Answer (score 1):

I could only manage to do that using url rewrite. The domain seems to be cookieless, so I think it is working as intended.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>

   <rule name="Static" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^static\.(.*?)$" ignoreCase="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/static/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
```